# Postgresql SUM with filter group column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sum

I have this relational data model

**product_table**

| ID | type | configurable_product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CONFIGURABLE | null |
| 2 | SIMPLE | 1 |
| 3 | SIMPLE | 1 |
| 4 | SIMPLE | 1 |

**product_source**

| ID | product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 3 | 20 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 |

A table that contains the list of products, with two types: configurable and simple. The simple products are linked to a configurable product.
A product_source table that contains the quantities of the different products.
I would like to make a query to retrieve all the quantities of the products, in this way:
If configurable product, then the quantity is the sum of the quantities of the simple products
If simple product, then it is the quantity of the simple product only.

Here is the expected result with the above data:

**result**

| product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 10 |

Do you have any idea how to proceed ?

For the moment, I have thought about this type of request, but I don't know how to complete the 'CONFIGURABLE' case

```sql
SELECT 
pr.id, 
pr.type, 
pr.configurable_product_id,
CASE
    WHEN (pr.type = 'SIMPLE') THEN ps.quantity
    WHEN (pr.type = 'CONFIGURABLE') THEN (????)
END AS quantity
FROM public."product" as pr
LEFT JOIN public."product_source" as ps
ON ps.product_id = pr.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window function` and `partition` for calculating `sum` of quantity (it was like `group by`)

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c2bd09e5289ab459374af4ff70539677)

```sql
SELECT 
  pr.id AS product_id,
  CASE
    WHEN (pr.type = 'SIMPLE') THEN ps.quantity
    WHEN (pr.type = 'CONFIGURABLE') THEN SUM(ps.quantity) over ()
  END AS quantity
FROM public."product" as pr
LEFT JOIN public."product_source" as ps
ON ps.product_id = pr.id
ORDER BY pr.id
```

Comment: Is this solution faster than the one coming from Hashed Tomato, with join ?

Comment: It's maybe faster because don't check `case` condition in every row. You can check with `explain` and compare both query

Comment: This code did not work when product table contains more than one CONFIGURABLE product isnt it?

Comment: Yeah, it does maybe not work. It is dependent on data and conditions. When using the windows function you should care about partition and filter. Maybe if append more data can improve query

Answer (score 0):

Your (...) is:

```
(
  SELECT SUM(ps2.quantity) 
  FROM product as pr2
  LEFT JOIN product_source as ps2
  ON ps2.product_id = pr2.id
  WHERE pr2.configurable_product_id = pr.id
)
```

Comment: Work fine, thanks !